# com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, exchange-server, starttls

```
package jmail;

import java.util.Date; import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Authenticator; import javax.mail.Message; 
import javax.mail.MessagingException; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class HtmlJavaSend {

public void sendHtmlEmail(String host, String port,
        final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
        String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
        MessagingException {

    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.man.com", host);
    properties.put("mail.25", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","mail.man.com");

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {new InternetAddress(toAddress)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    // set plain text message
    msg.setContent(message, "text/html");

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // SMTP server information
    String host = "mail.man.com";
    String port = "25";
    String mailFrom = "admin@man.com";
    String password = "Man";

    // outgoing message information
    String mailTo = "ji@man.com";
    String subject = "Hello my friend";

    // message contains HTML markups
    String message = "<i>Greetings!</i><br>";
    message += "<b>Wish you a nice day!</b><br>";
    message += "<font color=red>Duke</font>";

    HtmlJavaSend mailer = new HtmlJavaSend();

    try {
        mailer.sendHtmlEmail(host, port, mailFrom, password, mailTo,
                subject, message);
        System.out.println("Email sent.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Failed to sent email.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

The error is:

> eror run: Failed to sent email.
>   com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
>   port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect  at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)     at
>   jmail.HtmlJavaSend.sendHtmlEmail(HtmlJavaSend.java:62)    at
>   jmail.HtmlJavaSend.main(HtmlJavaSend.java:85) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
>     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2066)
>     ... 8 more BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: error which i get is

Comment: you only put a lot of code, add some description for your question.

Comment: this is my error Failed to sent email.
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)

Comment: Make up your mind. The stack trace you posted shows `java.io.IOException: Server is not trusted:`, which can only happen *after* a successful TCP connect; and there is no such message as 'connection refused: connect timeout'.

Comment: i corrected the stack

Comment: @ips You  must have put ‘local host’ as the host, not ‘mail.man.com’. The error message says so. Fix that.

Answer (score 5):

You have error here:

```
properties.put("mail.man.com", host);
properties.put("25", port);
```

It should be:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
```

Comment: I am trying to use html content in the email not only just text. I was able to send just text format but apparently html format is giving me issues
    Do i copy paste exactly? properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

 Because i tried krzosik i get error com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.jav‌​a:2100)

Comment: I can confirm that the port 25 is open . I ran a telnet session  via port 25 for , mail.man.com, and ip. They all returned a 202 service ready message.

So I do not believe it is ports or firewall access that is the reason for the refused connection.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

```
properties.put("mail.25", port);
```

you are connecting to the port offering plaintext SMTP. This is backed by your observation to receive `202 service ready message` message when using telnet.
But you are also setting properties to use TLS:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","mail.man.com");
```

If you use port 25 just don't enable TLS, or, use port `465` (standard port for SMTP with TLS) with TLS enabled.

Comment: `mail.25` doesn’t mean that. It doesn’t mean anything actually.